# Routing to embedded Modules/Bundles/Controllers in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

*I fully edited this post after doing research:*

I'd like to realize a sidebar in the admin section which is integrated in every page, f.e. http://example.com/admin/index/:

```
class MyController extends Controller {

    protected $modules = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->modules[] = "ModuleController:mainAction";
        $this->modules[] = "OtherModuleController:mainAction";
    }
    
    public function indexAction(Request $request){
        // do stuff here
        return $this->render("MyBundle:My:index.html.twig",$data);
    }
}
```

In the view should happen something like:

```
{% block modules %}
    {% for module in modules %}
        {% render module %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

So far so good, but these modules can contain forms which send post requests. I'd like to stay on the same page (http://example.com/admin/index/), so the action attribute of the form stays empty. The problem is: The post request will never be recognized by the Modules. So one idea was to hide a field in the according form that contains the name of the route, transform it to the according uri and send a sub request (in MyController):

```
public function indexAction(Request $request){
    if($request->request->has('hidden_module_route')){
        // collect all parameters via $request->request->keys()
        $uri = $router->generate($request->request->get('hidden_module_route'), $parameters);
        // 1: resolve the uri to the according controller and replace the target in the $this->modules array
        // or 2: (after step 1)
        $req = $request->create($uri, 'POST');
        $subresponse = $this->get('kernel')->handle($req,HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
        // inject the response into the modules and handle it in the view
    }
    [...]
}
```

That would work for me, but I'm not happy to have these responsibilities in the controller and it feels like there should be a better solution (one Idea is to register a `kernel.controller` listener that handles sub requests and injects the paths to the controller (which perhaps is marked via interface...)).

What do you think?

Comment: See http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html and scroll down to "Embedding Controllers". Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I dont think that triggers internal routing?! Depending on the post request i need another controller method...

Comment: Use PHP as the templating language and change the controller method name on the fly. Probably a bit hacky, but I have the feeling that I not properly understand all details of your question (or they aren't specified) so this is a more general solution then.

Comment: That would do the trick, but does not feel right for me. I did a little research on that topic and what i want todo is: create a new internal request based on the post variables to all registered modules (i know there are no modules in Symfony, but the terminology suits my needs). So i could hook up a listener and create internal requests via kernel but Im actually not shure if i'll be able to collect the responses and pass them back to the controller.

Comment: You should add that to your question, not in a comment ;)

Comment: @RCKY So essentially you're trying to have multiple forms on a single page and after submitting any of the forms, you want the user to be redirected back to the original page?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to send the main request to your modules, so that they can bind the form with it.

```
{% block modules %}
    {% for module in modules %}
        {% render module with {'mainRequest': app.request} %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And the module:

```
public function moduleAction(Request $request, Request $mainRequest)
{
    $form = ...;
    if ($mainRequest->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bindRequest($mainRequest);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // You can have a beer, that worked
        }
    }
}
```